# Not able to connect Hive database other than default using Hive Connector Jasper

Tags: hadoop, jasper-reports, hive

Softwares used

Jasper Studio 5.5
Apache Hadoop 1.2.1
Apache Hive 0.11.0
Inbuild Jasper Hive COnnector.

Issue:
Using Jasper Hive connector I am able to connect my reports to use Hive managed tables in Default database. However when I try to change the Hive connector url to other database I am getting error saying invalid url. Do anyone tell me the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Hive connection url only supports 'default' parameter at the moment. If you want to change the database you have to update the hive-site.xml.